# Internal Server Error 500 on Ajax Post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to make a request on a server using AJAX.

Now I always get an Internal Server Error 500. In the response I get: `"{" F ": {" F ": true," M ":" ServerError: null "}}".`

I don't know what I could be doing wrong. I would be very grateful for any suggestions.

This is my code:

```html
<script>
var daten =[{"O":"UPDATE","V":"IjMi"}]};
 
$.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify(daten),
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'https://...',
    type: 'POST',
    headers: {'X-GWT-Permutation':'07112C32C9E1BAE030C43E092EA21362'},
    accepts: 'text/html',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: Something is going wrong server-side. You need to investigate that (look at your error logs and such.)

Comment: What type of webserver do you have? Do you have any other source to test your web server and look if your method is working? Do you enable Access-Control-Allow Headers?

Comment: not correct syntax for var `daten =[{"O":"UPDATE","V":"IjMi"}]};` you got on `}` alone at the end

Comment: there is one extra `}` braces in `var daten` , try after remove that , `var daten =[{"O":"UPDATE","V":"IjMi"}];`

Comment: I think you should not include domain name : this should not be there https: //www.yourdomainname.com  and remove last flower bracket from var daten =[{"O":"UPDATE","V":"IjMi"}]

Comment: The string is much longer, I just wanted to shorten it to readability, so it is not the brace.
Server is an Apache HTTP. And yes "Access Control Allow Headers" is already allowed.

Answer (score 1):

one curly braces is missing from daten. It should be like 
var daten =[{"O":"UPDATE","V":"IjMi"}];

If You again facing same error(Internal Server Error 500) then you need to check your backend code because it is breaking in server side where you are trying to call from ajax call.